# Using grid-column-start causes auto-placement of grid items to stop working

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the below example, main should be getting pushed to the 2nd line when the screen size is decreased, but for some reason it stays in the first row even though the footer starts at column 3 and there's plenty of room for main to move down.

If I remove the grid-column-start/end from the footer, the grid is fully responsive and pushes main to the 2nd row when re-sized.

My thought was "maybe when positioning is involved, the items are 'popped' out of their normal grid-flow and are in their own little 'dimension' so-to-speak". However, when I add positioning to `main { grid-column-start: 4 }`, it doesn't 'pop' out of it's position and get pushed into the 'dimension of positioned grid items only'. It simply just stays on row 1 and moves to the right.

I apologize if the dimension stuff doesn't make sense but I just wanted to share what I thought was going on.

Example:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

footer {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

header {
  background: tomato;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

main {
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}

nav {
  background: limegreen;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

footer {
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <nav>Nav</nav>
  <main>Main</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what `grid-column` actually does in an `auto-fill` / `auto-fit` situation is freeze the column.

So with:

```
footer {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

... the items in the *third column* are locked in and will no longer wrap. As a result, the items coming before `main` – `header` and `nav` – are blocked from wrapping to the next line, and remain confined to the first row ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aj74vqdb/22/)).

If you try this instead:

```
footer {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

... the items in the *second column* are locked in and will no longer wrap. As a result, the item coming before `nav` – `header` – is blocked from wrapping to the next line, and remains confined to the first row. But the item coming after `nav` – `main` – is still free to wrap ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aj74vqdb/24/)).

Not sure where this is defined in the [grid spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), but that appears to be the rendering behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying

> In the below example, main should be getting pushed to the 2nd line when the screen size is decreased, but for some reason it stays in the first row even though the footer starts at column 3 and **there's plenty of room for main to move down**.

you are forgetting that this is not the expected behaviour.

The footer has been placed at column 3, so there are 3 columns.

**grid-auto-flow** is *row*, the default value.

So, even if there is plenty of room to move down, *main* will first try to fill the empty cell at column 3. It will not move to a new row because there is available space there, but it would do it if there was no more space available at the current row.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dx0mak7r/1/ - tried that and it still had the same behavior. What you say does make sense though.